# What type of data is showing on console.log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console.log

I'm wondering what type of data is the like of this:

[image]

I want to generate one properly in PHP, because that is the required type of a parameter in a certain JS function.

Is it a string, array, object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an array of strings. You can generate one in PHP using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode):

```
echo json_encode(array("36", "45"));
// => ["36", "45"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $phpArray = array(
          0 => "36", 
          1 => "45"
    )
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jArray= <?php echo json_encode($phpArray ); ?>;
</script>
```

Refrences

[json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode)

[array in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)